# Product of the Terms of a Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If I know that $a_1, a_2, \dots$ converges to some limit $c$, then is it always true that $\prod_{i=1}^n a_i = \Theta(c^n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. If $a_n=1+\frac 1 n$ then $a_n \to 1$. It can be shown (by taking logarithm and using harmonic series ) that $\prod_{k=1}^{n}a_k \to \infty$.